# Where should I install SSL behind ELB? Nginx or Node

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My config is Node->Nginx->ELB via Elasticbeanstalk

I have install my site certificate on ELB. So Client->ELB is over HTTPS

But from ELB I want to receive over HTTPS. Where should I install local cerf on, Nginx or Node?

If Nginx then how to give path to cerf in nginx config via EB?

Comment: Certificates for use in nginx need to be in local file system path, you can't use the ones created in ACM

Comment: yes that is correct, but how do i upload cerf to local path when i am using elasticbeanstalk or do i have to use s3 for that?

Comment: Ah, elasticbeanstalk. Lets then wait for someone who is expert there :) (in the meantime [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html) might help...)